# SQL date insertion from Excel results in wrong date value

Tags: sql, excel, vba, excel-2010, sql-date-functions

I have problem executing part of my SQL query from Excel. Note that the same query works from my Manager's PC, and both are on the same Regional settings in CP.

Here's code:

```vb
Do While Range("A" & CStr(Red)).Value <> ""

    Sql_Query = "UPDATE [DB-NAME] SET [Expiration Date] = '" & Format(Trim(Range("H" & CStr(Red)).Value), "yyyy-mm-dd") & _
       "' WHERE (No_ = '" & Trim(Range("A" & CStr(Red)).Value) & "') AND ([Pallet Place No_] = '" & Trim(Range("B" & CStr(Red)).Value) & "') AND " & _
       "([Item No_] = '" & Trim(Range("C" & CStr(Red)).Value) & "')"
    Set Rs = Conn.Execute(Sql_Query)
    'Rs.Close ' Closing query
    Set Rs = Nothing

    Red = Red + 1 'Switching to the next row after one is finished
Loop
```

When I execute this part, Mr. Code inserts code like this:

```
"UPDATE [DB-NAME] SET [Expiration Date] = '7627-09-30' WHERE (No_ = '267917') AND ([Pallet Place No_] = '11110102') AND ([Item No_] = '116000')"
```

Note: this is text that '*Add Watch*' option returns.

Even though in that 'H' column date is like '2018-12-30'.

Cell format in Excel doesn't make change. Its not important if its General or Text or Date or Custom-date, problem remains. And this thing with Mr. Code is consistent.

Comment: In some dialects of SQL you need to surround date literals with different characters (usually # ) rather than single quotes. Could this be it?

Comment: @HarassedDad I dont know if thats possible problem because same code works on another PC with the same SQL AND Regional settings.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Is that query works at all from yours computer? Try update other field (it's better number type).

Comment: other parts works fine, but whenever I try to insert date from any document to a db, I have same problem as here.